# How to find all inputs that make use of the php input filter to fully disable the php filter module?

Tags: input-formats

I want to disable the PHP Filter module on a large website, but going through all nodes, blocks and other fields where you could make possible use of the php filter would take eons.

Is there a simple way or method maybe by running SQL queries to find out where the php filter is used throughout my website?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Rather than re-inventing the wheel, just install the [Security Review](https://drupal.org/project/security_review) module, which has the following check:

> PHP or Javascript in content (nodes and comments and fields in Drupal 7)

For blocks you can check the format column in the block_custom table.

The difficult one is Views - I've yet to find a reliable way to locate rogue PHP in Views programmatically.

Comment: I guess if Security Review guys [wasn't able to](https://drupal.org/node/1831918) add a reliable check for Views, it may be simply next thing to impossible.

Comment: @Mołot : Just found a way to retrieve views which has php enabled please see my answer below.. It will be great to know it has any downsides or edge cases...

Comment: All I got is "OK Untrusted users do not have access to use the PHP input format." - with latest version. **It got me green when I had a block with php input format on front page**. Your answer seems to be simply untrue at the moment.

Comment: So, from what I can tell... the Security Review Module tells you that the php filter is being used... not what elements exactly are using it, which in a true security review would be helpful. This is however a good warning that further investigation is needed.

Comment: Related: [Find which views are using Views PHP](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/284053/88044)

Answer (score 7):

You can able to find all views which have php enabled by running below command in MySQL...

```
SELECT vv.name , vd.display_options
FROM views_display AS vd
LEFT JOIN views_view AS vv ON vv.vid = vd.vid
WHERE vd.display_options REGEXP '.s:[3]+:"php".*'
```

views_display table stores this information in [serialized](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) format.... I have tested above query works as expected.. Hope it helps to solve the views PHP riddle :-)

Comment: Looks good. Would need to test it a bit. In the meantime I took liberty of editing and cleaned up the way you wrote the query (without touching it's logic, names etc of course).

Comment: Thank you :-) I just verified and i can able to see views which has php enabled.. Let's hope it works for OP too..

Comment: This doesn't work for all views (e.g. those defined in code), and that regex could easily produce false positives...better than nothing though I guess :)

Comment: Using phpmyadmin you can very easily search across all columns of all tables, search for php and manually go through the results.

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but was first on my Google search.

There's a Contrib Module that is supposed to find all PHP entries:

[PHP Finder](https://www.drupal.org/project/php_finder)

> 'PHP Finder' module is used to find where the PHP filter format is used, whether in the node, block or views.

Comment: what about PHP used in Rules?

Answer (score 0):

The code from Anil Sagar above only works if the view is saved in the database. If the view is only in code it won't work. So, I wrote a little snippet that I run to save all the views to the db. Then I can use the MySQL snippet to surface php.

```
  $views = views_get_all_views();
  foreach ($views as $view) {
    if (empty($view->disabled)) {
      $view->save();
      drupal_set_message('view saved: ' . check_plain($view->name));
    }
  }
```