# Find which views are using Views PHP

Tags: 7, views

I have a project that is using [Views PHP](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_php), and I'd like to figure out which views are using PHP from this module. This will help me determine if I can easily remove the dependency on the module.

Is there a query or something else I can use to figure out what views are using this module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Searching cache_views as [this answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/284074/88044) suggested is a partial solution that helps, but a full solution will include views that are not cached.

In order to do this, you can export views to code (e.g. using the Features module), and search the views for `'php'` or `php` to find Global: PHP fields and sort criteria.

Answer (score 1):

Using the PHP filter in the fields should require you to use `<?php ?>` tags as part of the content.

The views data (unless its been exported with features) will sit inside the cache_views table in your DB, so you should be able to reliably find views using PHP filter by searching like so:

`SELECT * FROM cache_views WHERE data LIKE '%<?php%';`

There is probably a more sophisticated way of finding this.. but hopefully its a good start!

Comment: This is a cache, so data is not guaranteed to be there. For example, if the cache was just cleared, it will be empty.

Answer (score 0):

Searching the views table directly seems to be best approach:

```sql
SELECT
  v.vid,
  v.name,
  d.display_title
FROM
  views_display d
JOIN
  views_view v
USING
  (vid)
WHERE
  d.display_options LIKE '%<?php%'
ORDER BY v.name;
```

```
+-----+----------------------------------------------+-------------------------------+
| vid | name                                         | display_title                 |
+-----+----------------------------------------------+-------------------------------+
| ID  | VIEW MACHINE NAME                            | VIEW DISPLAY NAME             |
+-----+----------------------------------------------+-------------------------------+
```